# Having trouble updating cocoapods?

Tags: ruby, flutter, cocoapods

When I try to update cocoapods using `sudo gem install cocoapods` in command line (as suggested by flutter doctor) it says it successfully installed:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching cocoapods-1.9.3.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.9.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.9.3
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.9.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But then when I check the cocoapods version using `pod --version` it returns `1.2.0` which was the old version of cocoapods that I was using. In addition, the flutter doctor tells me that I still need to update cocoapods:

```
CocoaPods 1.2.0 out of date (1.8.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to
        your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I had recently also just updated Ruby to 2.6.3, I'm not sure if that has something to do with the problem.

I've tried just about every solution I could find on the internet, including

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

```
brew install cocoapods
```

```
brew reinstall cocoapods
```

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

None of it worked for me. I'm really stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Trying `sudo gem which cocoapods` and `sudo gem list cocoapods` to see all versions of gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below cmd to update certain verison(like `1.10.0`):

```sh
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.10.0
```

Then check the version with `pod --version`.

Have a nice day!